# Can the tyk.io Dashboard be customized with a different authentication method?

Tags: oauth-2.0, tyk

We are using version 2.0 of tyk.io, and we wanted to know if there is a way to customize the tyk.io dashboard ui to use a custom authentication method such as Oauth2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify - Do you mean using OAuth for controlling access to the tyk dashboard itself?

If so, take a look at Tyk Identity Broker - that should do the trick. https://tyk.io/tyk-documentation/concepts/tyk-components-2/identity-broker/

Comment: As mentioned by @Hirsty Tyk Dashboard quite extensible and you can implement almost any auth workflow for dashboard itself or for developer portal. For example your Dashboard access can be controlled using LDAP, and your developer portal using Github logins.

Here is repository itself, and examples of configuration: https://github.com/TykTechnologies/tyk-identity-broker

Hope it helps!